# Asymptotic running time for multiplying multivariate polynomials using Schönhage/Strassen

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity

**Question:**
I would like to ask the community where my following suggestion for an asymptotic bound for the running time of multiplying two multivariate polynomials using theorem $8.23 $ recursively fails.

In **Modern Computer Algebra** from *Joachim von zur Gathen* and *Jürgen Gerhard* theorem $8.23 $ states that the running time for multiplying two polynomials $ f, g \in R [t] $ both having degrees bounded by $ n $ over any commutative Ring $ R $ with $1 $ amounts to

$$ O^{\sim}(n) $$

arithmetic operations in the ring $ R $. Here $O^{\sim}(n)$ ignores logarithmic terms, the original result gives

$$ (18 + 72 \log_3 2) n \log n \log \log n + O (n \log n) $$

arithmetic operations in $ R $.

**My idea:**

Let $ f(x_1,..., x_m), g(x_1,..., x_m) \in K [x_1, ... , x_m] $ be two multivariate polynomials in which the power of $ x_i$ is at most $ n_i $. We can regard those polynomials as polynomials in $ x_m $ over the ring $ R_{m-1} = K [x_1, ... , x_{m-1}]$, then thoerem $8.23$ gives us a complexity of $O^{\sim}(n_m)$ arithmetic operations in $R_{m-1}$. Those operations are at worst again multplications of multivariate polynomials in $x_{m-1}$ (having degrees at most $n_{m-1}$ in $x_{m-1}$) over $ R_{m-2} = K [x_1, ... , x_{m-2}]$ and now we could use this procedure recursively to obtain an estimated running time of

$$O^{\sim}\left(\prod_{i=1}^m n_i\right)$$

operations in $K$.

Where does this arumentation not hold?

I'd be grateful for any kind of help or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific argument has the following gap, assuming you've quoted all relevant details.

While theorem 8.23  does say that you can multiply with $\tilde{O}(n_m)$ operations in $R_{m-1}$, it does not say anything about the *degrees* of the elements of $R_{m-1}$ you need to multiply.

---

I'm not sure why you're skeptical of the result. The runtime you derive *is* achievable; a simple method is [Kronecker substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_substitution). E.g. you can multiply two bivariate polynomials $f,g \in R[x,y]$ of degree less than $m$ in $x$ and degree less than $n$ in $y$ by computing the product of the two univariate polynomials $f(x, x^{2m})$ and $g(x, x^{2m})$ of degree less than $2mn$.